# How can I set a classifier as part of my version when building with the nebula release plugin?

Tags: gradle, version, netflix-nebula-plugins

My team has a shared library for some of our applications.
The shared library sets up configurations based on environment variables.
I am migrating the Environment variables to Vault.

I need to publish a new version of the library so I can test and deploy new versions of the applications to make sure they work when deployed with the new vaulted values.

We're using the [Nebula Release Plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-release-plugin) to easily control and increment version #'s.
Until the new vault feature is ready, I would like to avoid impacting the other developers, and set a *vault* classifier on my Shared Library builds.

How can I setup a classifier as part of the version number the *Nebula Release Plugin* creates?
I see `Major`, `Minor` and `Patch` in the documentation but no `Classifier`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I confused the issue.  `classifier` is actually set either when you build the jar, or as part of publishing. Not with the Release Plugin as part of versioning. (or at least that was how I figured out how to do it.)

I decided to put with the publishing code.

```
publishing {
   publications {
      binaryAndJavadoc(MavenPublication) {
         artifactId config.artifactId

         //compiled jar
         artifact(jar) { classifier = 'vault' }

         //javadoc
         artifact(javadocZip) { classifier = 'vault-javadoc' }
      }
   }
}
```